# How to publish a Gradle shadow jar without a shadow pom

Tags: gradle, artifactory, shadow, publishing, shadowjar

I use the shadow jar plugin (https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to create an extra jar file with all my dependencies packaged inside. I also would like to keep the default generated jar that has only my code & resources. This is pretty simple and straightforward until it comes to publishing the jars.

As my shadow jar has all its deps inside, its pom file is not a priority for me in terms of publishing. However if I follow the instructions laid out in the shadowJar plugin documentation (https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/publishing/#publishing-with-maven-publish-plugin)

```
publishing {
  publications {
    shadow(MavenPublication) { publication ->
      project.shadow.component(publication)
    }
  }
```

I end up with two different pom files (one for the regular jar file and one for the shadow jar) published to the **same** URL with one overriding the other. This behavior causes customers to download the default jar but without any dependencies in the pom file.

I tried many ways to disable shadowJar pom file but without any success. How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I just ignored the instructions in the plugin's documentation and published the shadow jar just like I publish my sources jar:

Simplest way to do this for a single project is:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        Library(MavenPublication) {
            from project.components.java
            artifact tasks.sourceJar
            artifact tasks.shadowJar
        }
    }
}
```

If you have multiple projects (not all having shadowJar plugin applied) and want to add this logic in the root project, you can do this:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        publishing {
            publications {
                Library(MavenPublication) {
                    from project.components.java
                    artifact tasks.sourceJar
                    if (project.tasks.findByName("shadowJar") != null) {
                        artifact tasks.shadowJar
                    }
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```